# how to handle Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 9 commits, and can be fast-forwarded. (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Tags: git

I have a remote repo on Github called aero.   I have a local repo on my laptop called aero.  I also have a repo called aero on my desktop computer.   I have been travelling and making edits in my local repo on my laptop and when I completed the work, I successfully pushed my work to the remote on Github.  I want to pull the contents from the remote onto my desktop and created a new branch to do additional edits, but when trying to git pull origin I get the following error.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    .DS_Store
    .idea/.gitignore
    .idea/aero.iml
    .idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml
    .idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml
    .idea/misc.xml
    .idea/modules.xml
    .idea/vcs.xml
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Also git status has the following message

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 9 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Comment: Is your branch behind the origin/main? If no, you can do a git reset --hard origin/main.

Comment: It's not a problem to be "handle"d. My recommendation is for you to go through a basic tutorial on Git that covers how to use it. It will answer these questions and more. Trying to use it in a "this command for this message" way, will end up damaging your repository and perhaps destroying your files. [This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) is a decent starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions tell you exactly what to do:

> Please move or remove them before you merge.

So you will need to delete these files then try `git pull` again.

I suggest closing your JetBrains IDE first.